# I want to loop through a database to create a collection for a dropdown on a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, loops, collections

Previously when creating forms in rails, when I was creating a dropdown box I have hardcoded the dropdown values. But now I want to create a drop down that will take the values from a database, loop through and find the values it needs to display in the drop down (preferably in alphabetical order). Is this possible and if so how?

I was kind of thinking something like this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :market_id %>
    <% array = [1, 2, 3] %>
    <%= form.text_field :market_id, collection: ["#{array}"] %>
  </div>
```

What I'm creating is a database of people and I want the dropdown to be able to look through that database and show the peoples address eg

```
collection: people.suburb
```

but some kind of loop to print them all

In previous websites I've done it in these two ways, hardcoding the values

options_to_select...

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :startcolour, "Start Colour" %>
    <%= select_tag(:startcolour, options_for_select(['white', 'black', 'clear', 'acrylic black', 'grey', 'mixed', 'other'])) %>
  </div>
```

And using collection:.....

```
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :fuel_type, collection: ["Petrol", "Diesel", "Hybrid"] %>
    <%= f.input :transmission_type, collection: ["Automatic", "Manual"] %>
    <%= f.input :location %>
    <%= f.file_field :pictures, multiple: true %>
```

I want the dropdown to grow as people add themselves to the database.

Not really sure where to start since I haven't messed with forms much and I'm not finding much love googling around.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [options_from_collection_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<%= f.select :startcolour, Model.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { :multiple => false, :size => 0 ,:class=> "", :id=> "" } %>
```

or

```
<%= f.select :startcolour, @model.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { :multiple => false, :size => 0 ,:class=> "", :id=> "" } %>
```

and in your corresponding controller action add `@model = Model.all`

Comment: I think this is not a good solution because If in future the address table will grow this will add the latency in rendering time as this query is getting fired on the view.

Comment: `Model.all` can be replaced with a variable like `@model` and declare the @model in corresponding  controller action

Comment: yes and you might want to select only those columns which you need to display on page. It reduces query time as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance variable in the controller with a select query.

in your controller method you can write
`@names = Model.all.select(:name).order(name: :desc)`

and in view you can use
`<%= f.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(@names, :name, :name, nil) %>`